# deb http://packages.ros.rog/ros/ubuntu xenial main? typo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that a typo exists in ros-latest.list on kinetic version.

http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.rog/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'  
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list  
deb http://packages.ros.rog/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

rog -> org, isn't it?

Actually I'm a starter, so I don't know where to notice that.
I Hope that it will fix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247920/deb-http://packages.ros.rog/ros/ubuntu-xenial-main?-typo?/) by [seungin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28515/seungin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> rog -> org, isn't it?

Yes, it should be `org`, but I'm wondering which page you are seeing this on. I just checked, and the page that has that text on it [wiki/kinetic/Installation/Sources](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Sources). As far as I can tell, it correctly has `.org`, not `.rog`:

[image: image description]

Last edit time is given as `2016-05-24 01:04:32` by @tfoote.

Can you give a direct link or post a screenshot?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seungin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28515/seungin/) on 2016-11-14**:
Oh, I'm so sorry for MY MIS-TYPING. This is caused by misunderstanding about the echo command. Thanks for your reply!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-14**:
No problem :).